# How to change htaccess for subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect subdomains like

```
^([a-z]{2}|ceb|haw|hmn|zh-CN|zh-TW).example.com/uk/(.*)$
```

for example:

```
de.example.com/uk/
ceb.example.com/uk/
```

redirect to `http://$1.example.com/en/`

for example:

```
de.example.com/en/
ceb.example.com/en/
```

how to change in `.htaccess`?

I try to use following but not works:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|ceb|haw|hmn|zh-CN|zh-TW)/uk http://$1.ts2.space/en [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the URL only. If you need to check on stuff like the host name, you need to use a RewriteCond for that.

Comment: `/uk/(.*)$` - What about the rest of the URL-path?

Comment: How to use the rewritecond for this request?

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. To match the hostname, you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (ie. the value of the `Host` HTTP request header).

In your example, you are redirecting to the same host, so there is no need to use a backreference in the *substitution* and you can omit the scheme+hostname entirely.

For example, the following redirects `de.example.com/uk/` to `de.example.com/en/` as per your first example.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2}|ceb|haw|hmn|zh-CN|zh-TW)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^uk/$ /en/ [R=302,L]
```

NB: Don't forget to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you.

Something is wrong. I add the code at first line in .htaccess, but it does not work.

I have an Apache.

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error? Undesirable redirect? Nothing? Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top? What is the actual URL you are requesting? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? Where is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: Nothing happened. I tried with "RewriteEngine On" at the top and without, the same situation. Other .htaccess rules works.

Comment: there is full .htaccess [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emFoVBb9SElH-HCDS3N3vmfhPM-9ydSP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Marcin And you put this entire rule at the very top of the `.htaccess` file? "What is the actual URL you are requesting?" Presumably when you request one of these subdomains you are seeing your website as normal? (WordPress does not redirect you?)